# Static class methods in pony?

Tags: ponylang

On code that doesn't make sense to have a this context, such as utility functions that relate to a `class`, is there a definition and calling syntax for "static class" methods in Pony or am I holding it wrong?

Comment: Better answers desired. Please feel free to add input.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't include them in an existing `class`, but stdlib uses this pattern of hacky workaround:

```
primitive Utils
  fun format(x: USize) => String
    x.string()

Utils.format(1234)
```

Comment: It's a shame because there's many times where you want to group utility functions with a class or call them directly without a this context, such as within a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a primitive as you answered, but another possibility is to use `fun tag`:

```
class Foo
  fun tag get_something(): String =>
    "Hello, world!"
```

This can be done for any type with methods (objects, actors, primitives), so long as you have a `tag` reference to it.